# How does this circuit give DC output?

Tags: transistors, transformer, dc, ac

I don't understand how this circuit works. I'm not sure if it's correct. It should give a DC output, but how would it do that?

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the circuit?

Comment: I give you a link... but I don't know it is right or not.. :) http://www.techtunes.com.bd/electronics/tune-id/105328 .. I simulate it.. it works.. but the voltage gradually increases.. from 0 to 9... I used all the resistance 10k while simulating...

Comment: I turn on the simulator and keep it up to approximately 20 minutes.. Now it is showing 130 V.. :)

Comment: The link you provide is undecipherable and not written in English (standard for this site)

Comment: You have the "input" and "output" labels swapped over. The circuit is an AC-output inverter, not a DC-output PSU.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: 
As drawn, this is a clever synchronous rectifier using BJTs as very-low-drop diodes. It would be suitable for a measuring instrument since the voltage drop is very low (no diode drop loss). A full-wave rectified output appears at the terminals.

If you reverse it (the way you'd normally draw it with flow from left to right), you get this:

This circuit is called a **[blocking oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_oscillator)**. The input is the DC and it produces a kind of square wave high voltage AC at the output of the transformer.

It depends on either the transistor coming out of saturation (due to insufficient base current for the current at the collector, which increases with on-time) or the transformer saturating (due to core saturation due to the high collector current) for the turn-off.

They're not very well controlled or very efficient circuits, but back in the dark ages, I made some simple inverters that were not much more than a 'filament transformer' a couple 2N3055s and some resistors (plus a snubber) (similar to [this](http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/TheTransistorAmplifier/TheTransistorAmplifier-P2.html#BLOCKING)) that could run small AC-powered measuring instruments from a 12VDC source.

[image]

Comment: If I do the opposite thing?? I mean if I give 220 or more AC input in the transformer then can't I get DC output??

Comment: Interesting question- does it work as a synchronous rectifier?

Comment: *IF* it works as a synchronous rectifier, the transistors would be in reverse saturation when conducting.

Answer (score 4):

I think you (or the author) got the input and output swapped. This seems to be a circuit for generating a sort-of 220V AC output  from a 5-12V DC input. The two transistors and the secondaries of the transformer (here used as primaries!) form an oscillator. A comparable circuit can be found [here](http://www.aaroncake.net/circuits/inverter.asp?showcomments=all):

[image]

Comment: may be.. then how it works... ? If you swap the input and output..

Comment: @RaihanKhalil Why would you want to know how this works if you are not sure what it does?

Comment: I don't see how this circuit could possibly oscillate.

Comment: The only thing on that site that gets remotely close to a schematic is a blurry hand drawn image which has a label "InPuT <gibbersih> 12 V D[C?]" and at the transformer "OUt 2?? V". Running the site through google translate suggests that one of the components needed is a car battery, so I think you are right in that this is meant to be some kind of 12V => 220V thing.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I think you're right; the schematic is for a 12VDC-to-220VAC inverter.

Comment: Nothing... just curiosity @Andyaka

Comment: The picture of the link that I gave is so hazy.. No-one can easily understand it so I give a diagram attached to my question...

Comment: One more thing is that the site is in **Bangla**. And there the author said that he give 220V AC and get 9V output.. He used this circuit for Charging his mobile phone... @PlasmaHH

Comment: @RaihanKhalil: I don't speak that language, but google translate suggests at multiple places that it is the other way round. Must be a funny glitch of it. (google translate outputs: "The output of this circuit is 220 volts to 350 volts AC bholtaja out!" "Now the 2-pin DIN socket on your charger." [last in the list of components to be connected] "any lead acid battery positive voltage must be entered.". Further note that the transistor he uses is nowhere rated near 220V

Comment: I am a Bangladeshi.. Our household supply voltage is 220V AC 50 Hz.. He didn't mention 220V but mention the main supply.. :) One more thing is that Google translator is not so well made for Bengali.. It gives some funny output.. So don't depend on Google translator.. @PlasmaHH

Comment: @RaihanKhalil: So you say that "220 volts to 350 volts" is entirely made up by google translate? very funny indeed then